# Create a box to to display the data from the event source using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, server-sent-events

I want to create a box to display the data from the event source using css.
For example,
[image]

In this picture, i want to create a box to load data from the php script. the new data appear at the top. i want to see new data at the top.As new data is being updated, the old data goes down and you cant see old data after 4 rows. I use css to achieve it. I use overflow to hide the the old data. Instead new data are at the bottom. Please help me. thank you.

my code is found below

php script

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        $dbhost     = "localhost";
        $dbusername     = "root";
        $dbpassword     = "netwitness";
        $dbname     = "abdpractice";
        $con = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die ('Error in connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

        //Select the particular database and link to the connection
        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname ) or die('Select dbase error '. mysqli_error());
        //Make A SQL Query and link to the connection

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `countryattack` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "data: [X] NEW ATTACK: FROM " . $row["countrysrc"]. " TO " . $row["countrydst"]. " \n\n";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.hidden {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div class="hidden" id="result"></div>

<script>


if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("shownewattack.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";

    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My output is like this
[image]

The output is that they show data at the bottom. This is not what I want.. Any ideas on how to do that..

My question is how to create a box to observe the data. As the script is being updated, the old data goes down. after the fourth row you cant see anything.new data will appear the top. Can you please help me. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute using [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) for concatenating `.innerHTML` of parent element.

```
const result = document.getElementById("result");

source.onmessage = function(event) {
  const node = document.createTextNode(event.data + "\n");
  if (!result.firstChild) {
    result.appendChild(node);
  else {
    result.insertBefore(node, result.firstChild);    
  }
};
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
<script>
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  let n = 0;
  
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let node = document.createTextNode(++n + "\n");
    if (!result.firstChild) {
      result.appendChild(node);
    } else {          
      result.insertBefore(node, result.firstChild)
    }
  }, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: OOOOOHH That is awesome!!!! But how to include the php script for that??? I have to go and learn node.insertbefore

Comment: What do you mean by "include the php script for that"?

Comment: I mean on how to use insertbefore for the data gotten from the php script

Comment: if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("shownewattacksqli.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  const node = document.createTextNode(event.data + "\n");
  if (!result.firstChild) {
   result.textContent = node;
  }
  else {
   result.insertBefore(node, result.firstChild);    
  }
 };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}

Comment: @Azhar The `php` code is already at the text of Question, one possible solution is at Answer.

Comment: if i remove  [object text] in the ! if condition, the data does not appear.

Comment: @Azhar  See updated post. You are correct. Good catch. Value set at `.textContent` should be a string, not an instance of a text node. Substitued `.appendChild()` for `.textContent = node`

Comment: \n is  not working  as  my output does not appear in a new line.

Comment: Use a `<pre>` element to preserve formatting of `"\n"` or also append a `<br>` element following appended `#text` node.

Comment: You are not "spamming the message". You are seeking coherent clarification as to the Answer. Why would you need to redefine `result` at each `message` event?

Comment: Oooops I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `countryattack` ORDER BY createdDate LIMIT 4");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "data: [X] NEW ATTACK: FROM " . $row["countrysrc"]. " TO " . $row["countrydst"]. "";
    }

echo "data: [X] NEW ATTACK: FROM " . $row["countrysrc"]. " TO " . $row["countrydst"]. "<br>";
```

That should do what you are looking for. Just add a createdDate into you Database when the row is added to the table and then order the data by that. Then Limit the records to 4. Also if you want the data on a new line you could add a < br > to the end of your echo. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

make sure u sort  your query using DESC or ASC in order to make them arrive accordingly. that sure solve the problem.